# ¿Cómo poner varias líneas de texto en un TextPane?

Tags: java

Una pregunta, ¿cómo puedo poner varias líneas de texto en un TextPane?
Lo intenté con el método `setText()` y se me sustituye cada vez por otra.
**¿Me podríais ayudar?**

Comment: Si necesitas una respuesta rapida.. `textPane.setText(textPane.getText() + mitexto);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues toma el texto anterior, mas el que vas a insertar, vale decir:

```
textPane.setText(textPane.getText() + textoInsertar);
```

Espero que te ayude, Exito!

Comment: Gracias!!      ¡¡No sé como no se me había ocurrido antes!! Muchas gracias de verdad

Comment: No hay problemas!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Se te sustituye porque debes dejar lo que estaba y luego agregar lo nuevo.

```
String texto_antiguo = jtextPane1.getText();
String texto_agregar = "...";
jtextPane1.setText(
              texto_antiguo + 
              texto_agregar
);
```